# How to manually test application lifecycle events in the Android emulator?

Tags: android, android-emulator

I'm working on an Android library where handling application lifecycle events is critical. I know how to unit test them, but I would like to manually test them in the emulator just to be completely sure things are working as expected. I can't figure out how to do this.

I need to test the onPause and onResume lifecycle events for the application. Is there a way to force this to happen? I've been closing my app and waiting, but it never seems to pause and just runs in the background indefinitely.

Comment: what do you expect to see when app is triggered onPause? how do you know it runs in background and doesn't get into onPause?

Comment: onPause and onResume aren't application lifecycle events.  They're Activity lifecycle events.  I think that's what you meant, but there's a BIG difference between the two

Comment: @GabeSechan That's correct. You can also register ActivityLifecycleCallbacks at the application level and get all lifecycle events, which you can use to get information about the state of the entire application.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the steps to test the **onPause** manually and **onResume**.

1. Press the home button on the emulator to send your app to the background. This should trigger the **onPause** event in your app.
2. Open the app again from the app drawer or recent apps list. This should trigger the **onResume** event in your app.
3. Lock the emulator by clicking on the power button in the emulator toolbar. This should also trigger the **onPause** event.
4. Unlock the emulator by dragging the lock screen. This should trigger the **onResume** event.
5. Change the device orientation using the rotate button in the emulator toolbar.
6. This will cause the activity to be destroyed and recreated, triggering the **onPause** and **onResume** events.

You can use **ADB commands** to simulate lifecycle events. For example,

```
adb shell am send-trim-memory <your_package_name> MODERATE
```

This will simulate a memory trim, which might lead to **onPause** being called.

**KEEP IN MIND**

- sometimes, the Android OS may not call **onPause** immediately, especially if the system has enough resources to keep your app running in the background. The system may decide to keep your app in a paused state for optimization purposes.

Comment: Your keep  in mind is incorrect.  onPause is ALWAYS called immediately.  onDestroy may wait or never be called, but pause is called the instant an Activity is no longer in the foreground.  It's called before onResume of the next Activity.  onStop can wait a bit in some circumstances, but will be called very quickly if your Activity completely leaves the screen, and will always be called if you go to another app

Comment: @GebeSechan  You're correct, and I appreciate it. But, I want to clarify the point to avoid confusion:

**onPause** is generally called immediately when an Activity is no longer in the foreground. However, in certain situations, especially when the system has enough resources, the OS may keep the app paused for optimization purposes before calling onStop or allowing the Activity to be destroyed. This behavior is not always consistent and may depend on various factors, including the device's available resources and the system's decisions on resource management.